# How to check, if HDD is in sleep mode?

Tags: suspend, external-hdd

I run a server with Ubuntu 18.04, that has HDDs connected via USB ports and I want to check, whether the HDDs are put into sleep mode. How can this be done on Ubuntu 18.04? Ideally via Terminal, since it's a headless server.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo hdparm -C DEVICE` will do it e.g.

```
sudo hdparm -C /dev/sdd1
dev/sdd1:
 drive state is:  active/idle
```

or for a sleeping device it will return:
 `drive state is:  standby`

Also see the `smartctl` command although I have not used it.

Comment: Ok, maybe I have a USB-SATA bridge, that doesn't support these commands. "SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 01 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 drive state is:  unknown"